# apply effects to specific lis using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I can do this in jquery but for some reason my boss prefers cutting the server request down to 32kb than using the magic of jquery.  So, How can I apply effects to all `li` tags on click using plain javascript?

I have tried `getElementById` but this only works on ids.  not very good with javascript as well. My `li` is so basic, it doesn't have class name.

EDIT:
Want to hide all `li` on click.  Tried this from one of the answers but error saying

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByTagName(...).style is undefined

```
document.getElementById('holder').getElementsByTagName('li').style.display="none‌​";
```

many thanks.

Comment: What type of effects were you looking to apply to your `li`'s? Also, can you post your code of what you have tried already?

Comment: What kind of effects do you want to apply on those _li_ elements? Did you request the jQuery server from the same webserver where you're application runs and which requests shall be cut down to 32Kb? If yes, consider using a Content Delivery Network like http://code.jquery.com/

Comment: just want to hide all the li when button is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('li');` this will return all li-s. Or get li s from specific element:

```
document.getElementById('myelementid').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

**EDIT** hiding all `li` elements inside element with id- "holder":

```
var lis = document.getElementById('holder').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
    lis[i].style.display="none‌​";
}
```

Comment: ... and then loop over the resulting NodeList.

Comment: document.getElementById('holder').getElementsByTagName('li').style.display="none"; -- this returns an error, what did i do wrong?

Comment: @SaintDee Like I said: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList. You have to iterate over this manually using a `for` loop, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var allLis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'), thisLi, i, l;
for(i=0, l=allLis.length; i<l; i++){
    thisLi = allLis[i];
    // do something to 'thisLi' here
}
```